# import .pde file (processing file) into blender

Tags: processing, dxf, blender-2.49

I have a "Processing" file (written in "Processing" i.e. a pde file) which has a model and its transformations such as open, close, scale, rotate ..

How can I import this file into Blender 2.49?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so. You have to create your model in processing and then export it with a additional library in a format blender can import. There is a lib for exporting [dxf files](http://processing.org/reference/libraries/dxf/index.html) and i guess [toxicLib](http://toxiclibs.org/) has also the possibility to export 3d files as stl files.

Comment: So if i create a model with its movements (for example) using processing and retype the original code as the exmple shown in http://processing.org/reference/libraries/dxf/index.html for using dxf library . now is it possible to import it from blender ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [modelbuilder](http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/2011/04/06/code-modelbuilder-library-public-release/) library and [UGeometry](http://workshop.evolutionzone.com/code/modelbuilder/javadoc/unlekker/modelbuilder/UGeometry.html).

You'll import modelbuilder e.g. :

```
import unlekker.util.*;
import unlekker.modelbuilder.*;
import unlekker.modelbuilder.filter.*;
import ec.util.*;
```

Load UGeometry:

```
UNav3D nav;
UGeometry model;
```

And write with the `UGeometry.writeSTL` method.